# How to protect image from website visitors?

Tags: image, browser

How to protect images on a website from the visitor?

I read some articles to protect images by disabling right-click. Is there any other option? Because disabling the JS can be easily done in the browser and images can be downloaded. However, most people won't do that. There are some extensions and plugin can be used to enable the right-clicking. In that scenario how to disable the extension like that, because images on the website are important. The ultimate aim of the question is How to protect the image?. Anyone has an idea about this.

Comment: There is no way to reliably protect images if you display them - if your visitor can view the image, it is already downloaded to the local device.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options [here](https://graphpaperpress.com/blog/protect-website-image-stealing/).

With all that being said, watermarks can be edited out and copyright notices can be ignored. A dedicated attacker will be able to get the images by virtue of your web-server sending them over; The best you can do is make this as difficult as possible for the average person. This may put users off of visiting your site, so you do need to find a good balance.